# Devices with static IP not routable when connected to wireless AP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, wireless-access-point, static-ip

I'm not very experienced with networking, but trying to set up a few static IP address on my home network but running into some trouble.

I have a Netgear DGND4000 which is acting as a router and DHCP server (with WiFi turned off.) Connected to this is a TP-Link EAP225 Wireless AP.

Wireless devices with a dynamic IP address connect fine through this and appear in the router's attached devices list.

However wireless devices configured with a static IP address connect to the AP (I can see them on the AP's connected clients list) however they do not appear in the router's attached devices list (and they are not accessible from other devices.)

If I change to use just the WiFi on the router, (and disable the AP) then all the devices work fine.

Everything is in the same subnet, and the devices with a static IP are configured with the gateway as the router's IP address.

How can I get the router to successfully route to the static IP devices when they are connected via the AP? Many thanks.

**Edit**

Some additional information that might be relevant - the AP is connected to the router via an unmanaged switch, Tenda SG108.

**Edit 2**

It seems the problem isn't limited to devices with a static IP. I can't ping any devices connected to the EAP225. I've installed WireShark on my laptop and I can see it sending ARP requests during a ping, but there aren't any responses from any device connected to the EAP225. I run 2 SSID's on the AP, one of them for guests. I have turned off SSID isolation completely (was previously only enabled on the guest network) however that hasn't help either.

Comment: static ip devices can ping Netgear (the Router)? if yes can ping 8.8.8.8 or any internet ip?

Comment: Yes, I can successfully ping the router, and the outside world from a device with a static IP when connected via the AP.

Comment: As I do not own an TP-Link EAP225 Wireless AP is hard to tell but if the AP has a Guest network then start looking in that direction in the config. There might be an option to shield the standard network from the guest one.

Comment: Yes it supports a guest network, and also has SSID isolation (this is off for both SSID's I'm running.) I've updated my question with some further information from some ping tests and WireShark. It appears like the EAP225 is somehow preventing communication to any device connect to it.

Comment: Can you give us a static IP and subnet of one of the AP devices and also the IP and subnet that is assigned by DHCP to a host not on the AP?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch An example static IP is 192.168.0.10, and the subnet is 255.255.255.0, gateway 192.168.0.1. When connected to the router another laptop is assigned 192.168.0.13, subnet 255.255.255.0, and gateway 192.168.0.1. It's pingable in that state. If I move the same laptop back to the AP, it gets the same details from DHCP, however is no longer pingable.

Comment: Last night, I had some success, with all devices connected to the AP working (after a FW update and reboot of the EAP225.) However this morning things are not working again - with the same problems.